# How is this question considered homework?

Tags: discussion

This one is on hold, but I'm mystified as to why it is classified as homework.  Seems like a legit question, though no evidence of research etc.  I'm ok with the hold, just not the reasoning.

https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/41889/high-mpv-and-low-platelet-count

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is the reason that is used when vote to close is based on no evidence of research. Like with the flags, there are limited options for close vote reasons and sometimes they get shoehorned into the most relevant reason.

However that also does not mean that every vote to close was based on that. There only needs to be 5 votes to close, but they do not have to all be for the same reason. From my perspective, that is a question related to medicine and should likely be on topic on another SE site.

Comment: I see, so it's not that it's a homework question so much as the OP didn't do any homework in the first place.

Comment: @Minnow If you are interested in knowing more about the discussion on "Homework Questions" as it relates to Bio SE, Typing homework in the search box at the top right of Meta Bio SE will yield 5 pages of Q & A on the subject.